# Ajax function failing to hit method on code behind on server

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax function

```
 var jsonId = JSON.stringify(sortedIDs);
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { ids: jsonId },
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Intranet/Dev/TestSortTable.aspx/GetData",
        success: function (msg) {
               alert(msg.d + "success");
        },
        error: function (response) {
               alert("an error has occured");
        }
});
```

And the following method in the code behind page

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetData(string[] data)
    {
        return "this is the string from the code behind file";
    }
```

The error I am getting is a 500 internal server error. If I add .cs to the TestSortTable.aspx I get a 404 not found error. This is the first time I have implemented an Ajax function and I am at a loss as to what I have done wrong. I should add that sortedIDs is defined elsewhere.

Comment: Are you 'hitting' the webMethod?  You can verify by putting a break point at/before the return line.

Comment: It is coming back as success but I do not seem to be hitting the web method and I can not get the message back from the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not sending the parameters as JSON. You're converting `sortedIDs` to JSON, but being wrapped into an object that gets sent as URL-encoded data. You need to do:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({data: sortedIDs);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: json,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Intranet/Dev/TestSortTable.aspx/GetData",
    success: function (msg) {
           alert(msg.d + "success");
    },
    error: function (response) {
           alert("an error has occured");
    }
});
```

Also, `datatype:` should be `dataType:`

Comment: Check your server log to see the reason.

Comment: Does `"/Intranet/Dev/TestSortTable.aspx/GetData"` need to have .aspx? because that looks strange to me.

Comment: Also, stringify should match the c# parameter, `var json = JSON.stringify({data : sortedIDs);`

Comment: So the c# parameter should be string[] or something else ?

Comment: @EmptyWaterHoles it depends what sortedIDs is

Comment: sortedIDs is an array of strings

Comment: It is now working. What I had to was not use dataType and contentType. I now get undefined for msg.d + success back. However when I do msg.ToString I get unexpected results. This is just another learning curve for me. And I will research a solution on stackoverflow. Thanks @lloyd for the advice and Barmar for your solution.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I failed to see the edit that @Barmar made. That  line is crucial. var json = JSON.stringify({`data`: sortedIDs}); It is hitting the method and returning the string. All Good. Thanks